# ASP.NET MVC 4 form post variables are null in receiving controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, post

I have this model:

```
  public class WorkflowImport {
    public bool IsLive { get; set; }
    public string DateTimeCreated { get; set; }
    public string CreatedByUser { get; set; }
    public string VersionComments { get; set; }
    public string VersionNumber { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }

    public List<WorkflowProcess> WorkflowProcesses { get; set; }
  }
```

A partial view:

```
@model <FullyQualifiedPathTo...>.ViewModels.WorkflowImport

<div class="subSectionHeader">Upload New Workflow Profile</div>
<div class="AccountDetailLine">
  @using ( Html.BeginForm( "UploadNewMatrix", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" } ) ) {
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Select Local File:</td>
        <td>
          <div class="upload-wrapper">
            <input type="file" name="file" id="xlsfile" />
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Version Comments:</td>
        <td>
          @Html.TextBox( "comments", Model.VersionComments, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "textboxUploadField" } } )
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Version Number:</td>
        <td>
          @Html.TextBox( "version", Model.VersionNumber, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "textboxUploadField" } } )
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Select whether this file upload will update<br />
          the live workflow matrix or just the "What If" test matrix</td>
        <td>LIVE @Html.RadioButtonFor( model => model.IsLive, "True" )
          "What If" @Html.RadioButtonFor( model => model.IsLive, "False" )
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="submit-wrapper">
      <input type="submit" value="Import Now" id="form_submit" class="ovobutton" />
    </div>
  }
</div>
```

and a receiving controller/method:

```
public class HomeController: Controller {
    // POST /Home/UploadNewMatrix
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadNewMatrix( WorkflowImport workflowImport ) {
      return View( workflowImport );
    }
}
```

But when I enter some values into the two textboxes and click the submit button, I get null values in the bound object on the controller, when checking in the debugger.

I don't know why this is happening, because I used an almost identical pattern (including file upload with "multipart/form-data") on a previous project and was able to get the values successfully.

Is there something obvious I have not seen here? The difference between this new application and the previous is that it is a partial view in amongst a lot of jquery, but I don't see how that could make a difference. Also, I need to use traditional file upload as the target browser is IE8 and does not support HTML5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For correct binding, name html element must equal property name

property:

```
  public string VersionComments { get; set; }
```

View:

```
   <tr>
        <td>Version Comments:</td>
        <td>
          @Html.TextBox("VersionComments", Model.VersionComments, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "textboxUploadField" } } )
        </td>
      </tr>
```

Note: i agree with Jacob. Using `@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.VersionComments)` more flexible approach, but my example demonstrates binding principle.

Comment: This works, but if you refactor `VersionComments` by renaming it, you'd also have to update the string "VersionComments". The `{Input}For` methods are much more maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting back null because the `name` of the inputs don't match what the model binder expects. To help you create the right names, ASP.NET MVC has some useful helper methods. Instead of:

```
@Html.TextBox(
    "comments", 
    Model.VersionComments, 
    new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "textboxUploadField" } } )
```

...do this instead:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(
    m => m.VersionComments, 
    new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "textboxUploadField" } } )
```

This will use the value of `VersionComments`, and it will also give the input the name `VersionComments` so that it knows to plug this into the model when posting.